# Who is this figure in Batman V Superman Dawn of Justice

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the Ultimate Edition of *Batman V Superman Dawn of Justice*, there's this scene (image below) where Lex Luthor is talking to a hologram of a large figure before being arrested in the Genesis Chamber:

[image]

Can someone give details who is this? And those three cubes in front of him. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Who was the horned creature Luthor was seen with in Batman V Superman: Ultimate Edition?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/56225/49)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bustle. com explains](http://www.bustle.com/articles/150551-batman-v-superman-deleted-scene-clarifies-the-ending-teases-justice-league-villain-video):

> Fortunately, now that we've seen this deleted scene, we won't have to
>   wait for future films to explain it. **This demon is a DC baddie named
>   Steppenwolf, a general from the planet Apokolips in the service of the
>   fearsome tyrant Darkseid.** (Think Marvel's Thanos, only with a face
>   made out of stone.) **Those cubes he's holding are Mother Boxes**, like
>   the one glimpsed in Cyborg's brief cameo, which are **basically living
>   supercomputers that grant their bearer mystical powers.** (Think
>   Marvel's Infinity Stones, only square.)